# How can I grep patterns in a fasta file, then print all those cooresponding sequences to a fasta file?

Tags: linux, bash, bioinformatics

I've had so much help with code errors when I've used this page. I really appreciate how much everyone wants to help out!!! I am brand new to any kind of coding and whooooooh this is a learning curve.

Anyways, I am trying to use the grep command to search for matching sequences from a list of patterns that are in my patterns.txt file.  I am trying to take those sequences, and write a new .fasta file for each one and put them into a new directory. I am trying to do this all in bash.

This is the bash script I wrote, but I'm not getting any output at all (except the directory gets made which is not that useful)

Edit**** for clarity: my question is I need to crease a FASTA file for each pattern that contains all the genes and their corresponding sequences that have that pattern. I want to name each file after the pattern and output it into a new directory. Ithink my original question was a little confusing!

```
mkdir SEQUENCE-MATCHES



for pattern; do
        grep -B1 $pattern my_file.fasta
done < patterns_file.txt > SEQUENCE-MATCHES/$pattern.fasta
```

This isn't outputting anything at all. I could manually run grep on all of the patterns, but it's too long to be realistic.

Comment: grep -f pattern_file.txt

Comment: I need the patterns to be separated, that's why I'm trying to use a loop here.

Comment: Is the input definitely sequential rather than interleaved?

Comment: How many patterns (10s, 1000s, millions)? How large is `my_file.fasta` ?

Comment: there are 30 or so patterns, and my_fasta.file has several hundred

Comment: I moved the > and still not getting anything :(

Comment: I don't think its interleaved

Comment: Yes, 1000 and 500

Comment: I need to create a FASTA file for each pattern that contains all the genes and their cooresponding sequences that have that pattern. I want to name each file after the patter and output it into a new directory. Maybe my original question wasn’t clear enough?

Answer (score 0):

`for pattern; do` doesn't set `pattern` the way you want.

Also, you merged all the output into a single file.

Try:

```
while read pattern; do
    grep -B1 "$pattern" my_file.fasta > SEQUENCE-MATCHES/"$pattern".fasta
done < pattern_file.txt
```

Note that this code also creates an empty output file for each pattern that doesn't match.

Comment: This worked!! thank you. Where would I go to learn about how my code and your code are different? I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Hard to give advice. Search for bash tutorials and see if any are at the right level for you?